# XAMPP mysql.sock is missing

Tags: mysql, linux, xampp, mysql.sock

I installed XAMPP from the apachefriends.org following these instructions: http://www.apachefriends.org/en/xampp-linux.html#377 .

The problem is that file /opt/lampp/var/mysql/mysql.sock is missing. How can i get this file?
Thing is I want to run an easy MySQL command learning tool and I get this error that the file is missing. (Warning: PDO::__construct() [pdo.--construct]: [2002] No such file or directory (trying to connect via unix:///opt/lampp/var/mysql/mysql.sock) in /opt/lampp/htdocs/SID/sid.php on line 188)

XAMPP is running ok, I started it with sudo /opt/lampp/lampp start. http://localhost/ works fine. I checked /opt/lampp/etc/my.cnf and it's ok, it contains this data http://pastebin.me/8d6b367a7ee76be70f944d9b960bb8f0

Please help, how can I get that mysql.sock?

Thanks

Comment: You may first make sure that mysql server is started as this required file is a socket.

Comment: as recommendation: dont use xampp on linux, its ok for windows because setting everything up from hand is horrible but on linux its just a performance loss. just install php5, php5-mysql, apache2 and mysql-server and ur done. if you use xampp you wont get any updates and ur server is vulnerable, if you install it from the repos ur mostly not vulnerable.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I saw other posts on the internet regarding this issue and no solution. I'm afraid you're right

Comment: K1773R Could not agree more..  Nothing but problems with xampp on linux. Setup is much easier without xampp on linux.  Ubuntu 16.10 here.

Comment: i went for xampp because i kept having problems with my own installations of php and mysql. i am still battling this issue of missing socket file and im on macos

Answer (score 13, accepted):

execute the next command in a Terminal windows:

ps -ax|grep mysql

And you can see a result like this:

--socket=/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/var/mysql/mysql.sock --port=3306

Bes Regards

PS: I use MAC OS X

Comment: i dont see this result i only see : 27313 ttys003    0:00.01 grep mysql

Answer (score 2):

I think you are running other instance of mysql..

try this :

```
/opt/lampp/bin/mysql -u *user* -p
```

and then enter your password when asked for.. Hope this helps..

I had a similar case, when putting only mysql, because that way it wasnt called lampp stack mysql but `/usr/bin/mysql` (which you can find typing --> which mysql)

Answer (score 2):

in ubuntu

/opt/lampp/var/mysql/mysql.sock